# React JS grouping a cart

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, lodash

In my e-commerce (in ReactJs) i built a cart object with the following format

```
[
  { id: 1,
    name: 'product name',
    price: '20',
  },
  { id: 3,
    name: 'Other product',
    price: '25',
  },
 { id: 1,
    name: 'product name',
    price: '20',
  },
]
```

Now, at checkout page i need to group products and i used:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
const grouped = _.groupBy(cart, (scart) => scart.id);
```

gropued result in an object like:

```
{ 1: [{id:1, name,name: 'product name', price: 20}, {id:1, name,name: 'product name', price: 20}] 2: [{id: 2, name:'Other product', price: 25}]}
```

but when i try to use map on the grouped object i got an error (grouped.map is not a function)

is there a way to rebuild grouped as an array or should i use `foreach` in the grouped object?

Comment: please share the code that you have tried and the desired result

Comment: @popeating grouped is an object, what Object methods allow to loop over object keys/values?

Comment: {Object.entries(grouped).forEach(([key, value]) => (
          <p>{value[0].name}</p>
        ))}
but it did not work, even if value has vaule

Answer (score 3):

The `groupBy` method returns an object which could be converted to a 2D array using `Object.values(grouped)`, then use two map functions to loop through arrays content :

```
{Object.values(grouped).map((group,i)=>{
   return <ul key={i}>
       {group.map((prod,j)=>{
          return <li key={j}>{prod.name}</li>
      })}

     </ul>
})
}
```

if you want to show only the first item in the nested array you could do :

```
{Object.values(grouped).map((group,i)=>{
   return <p key={i}>{group[0].name}</p>
})
}
```

Comment: it's not working, also "Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function" on the first map

Comment: Yes i missed the return before `<ul>`, I added please check the edited answer

Comment: Thank you, but its not what i was looking for, this way it prints all and not the grouped, so i was not in need to group and i could simple print the cart
this one seems the way, but i can't understand why it doesnt print out
{Object.entries(grouped).forEach(([key, value]) => ( <p>{value[0].name}</p> ))}

Comment: forEach doesn't return a content to display, do you want to show only the first item in each nested array?

Comment: Solved it pushing the foreach return in an array and then mapping it

Answer (score 1):

Lodash's `_.map()` works can iterate objects:

```
import React from 'react';
import _ as * from 'lodash';

const Checkout = ({ cart }) => {
  const grouped = _.groupBy(cart, 'id');

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="uppercase">{cart.length} products in cart</h1>
      <div>
        {_.map(grouped, (single) => (
          <p>
            {single[0].name} - {single.length}
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Note**: It's better to import specific lodash functions, because the newer versions support tree shaking, so I would use import like this:

```
import { groupBy, map } from 'lodash';
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved

```
import React from 'react';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
const Checkout = ({ cart }) => {
  const grouped = _.groupBy(cart, (scart) => scart.id);
  let cartform = [];
  Object.entries(grouped).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    cartform.push(value);
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="uppercase">{cart.length} products in cart</h1>
      <div>
        {cartform.map((single) => (
          <p>
            {single[0].name} - {single.length}
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```